# SQL Query Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8

I have 4 tables, one is veg_tech and its structure is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `veg_tech` (
`VEG_TECH_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `VALI` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `JAAT` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `BOR_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FERTILIZER_KG_ROP_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `BOR_DISTANCE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `BEW_BARNA_DAR` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

now, the BOR_ID, FERTILIZER_KG_ROP_ID and DOR_DISTANCE_ID are foreign key, now the foreign table has data too, and i want to display all the data from this table as well as all the data from other tables too. Could someone help

Comment: use left join to select data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'veg_tech' v
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON v.BOR_ID= t2.BOR_ID
LEFT JOIN table_3 t3 ON v.FERTILIZER_KG_ROP_ID = t.FERTILIZER_KG_ROP_ID 
LEFT JOIN table_4 t4 ON v.DOR_DISTANCE_ID = t4.DOR_DISTANCE_ID ;
```

Comment: What do i need to do, if just want to get the id of veg_tech and not of dependend table

Comment: Just replace `SELECT *` with `SELECT "column names you want to display seperated by ,"`